# MySQL Connections, increases the load insanely

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

And thanks by take your time reading/answering my question.

Before start a MySQL connection this is the usual loading time:
0.0182s

(I'm not working on a "powerful" computer but decent).
Then, after open the MySQL connection using the PDO class.

```
class Dbdriver extends \PDO
{
    private $con = array();

    private $dns;

    private $query;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con[0] = 'mysql';
        $this->con[1] = 'localhost';
        $this->con[2] = 'db_name';
        $this->con[3] = 'mysql_user';
        $this->con[4] = 'mysql_pass';

        $this->dns = $this->con[0].':dbname='.$this->con[2].';host='.$this->con[1];
        $connection = new \PDO($this->dns, $this->con[3], $this->con[4]);

        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * from Users");
        $query->execute();
        print_r($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        $connection = NULL;
    }
}
```

Also i try a simple query for see if it works (it does).

But then comes the sad answer, the load increases insanely to: 1.0345s

I have a few questions to ask.
Is it normal?
Can you share some tips for provide a faster load?

PD: I'm a bit newbie and this is giving me a big headache.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, does it make a difference?

Comment: ...and how many users are in your table?

Comment: `fetchAll()` is retrieving all users. If there are a lot of them, it may take a second to stream them all back from the RDBMS.

Comment: The table only has 3 users. And the insane increase starts with the connection.

Comment: That's what I also thought, the way you've setup your DB connection. It seems to be sifting through arrays, there are other ways of doing this. Try this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240725/1415724

Comment: Woah, it works @Fred-ii- thank you very much! also thanks by all the help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it @Drakantas

Comment: I had a funny feeling that the slow speed was caused due to going over all those arrays. @Drakantas cheers