# Why the connection class does not make the connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to OOP and PHP, so I have a problem here. Could someone tell me, what I am doing wrong with my connection class? It does not connecting to the database, I've tried to var_dump($this) in try statement and it either doesn't work. Also I am changing my 'dbname' to a random name and the code still 'works'..

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    class connection {
        // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
        public function __construct() {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employee';
            // Setting options
            $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // Making the connection to the database
            try {
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    $connection = new connection();
?>
```

Comment: Try `echo $e->getMessage();` in the `catch` to see the error details. It works because of the try catch block

Comment: You should enable Displaying errors first. Your class properties are not defined yet.

Comment: and yes put on top of script `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and 
`ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: @sand thank you, it helped, there was wrong database name... Could someone tell me if my code structure is good or not?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Doesn't it has to be 'single responsible principle'? I.e 'connection' is in 1 class, inserting values to the database is in another file class and etc? Besides that, I've tried your code, which you've posted in my previous question, but it didn't worked, so I'm trying to write my own from beginning according to your code.

Comment: You understands this principle quite perverted way. thinking like this, there will be only classes with single method only. If you want to try my code, then try it with vanilla PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that's not a duplicate of this question that you marked this with. here we the Op is having a problem with a connection class,

Comment: this would been better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240500/creating-a-database-connection-class-pdo-and-fetch-data

Comment: Or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864856/pdo-connection-class

Answer (score 0):

Every method in class has to return something.
Try:

```
  class Connection {

   private $connection;    
    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employee';
        // Setting options
        $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Making the connection to the database
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function DoSomething()
    {
         //do something with your $this->connection and return some value;
    }
}
$connection = new Connection();
echo $connection->DoSomething();
```

Comment: Naming convention: Better to start a class name with Capital letter

Comment: ^ true, edited--